# Can't import excel with 2 millions rows mysql laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I can't import mysql data with 2 million rows at the moment I can only import 8500 data.If I am over 8500 it will appear

" 503
Service Unavailable
The server is temporarily busy, try again later! "

[image]

```
<?php

namespace App\Imports;
use App\Models\{Datalead,Debitur,Perusahaan,Saldolist};


use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\{ToCollection, WithHeadingRow, WithCalculatedFormulas,WithMultipleSheets };

class DataleadImportSaldolist implements ToCollection, WithHeadingRow, WithCalculatedFormulas,WithMultipleSheets 
{
    /**
    * @param Collection $collection
    */

    public function sheets(): array
    {
        return [
            0 => $this,
        ];
    }
    public function collection(Collection $collection)
    {
        //print("<pre>".print_r($collection,true)."</pre>");
        foreach ($collection as $row) 
        {

                    $saldo = Saldo::create([

                        'Tanggal' => $row['tanggal'],
                        'KodeCab' => $row['kode_cab'],
                        'NamaCab' => $row['nama_cab'],
                        'KodeKLN' =>$row['kodekln'],
                        'SentraKode'=> $row['sentra_code'],
                        'KodeKCP' => $row['kodekcp'],
                        'AccountType' => $row['account_type'],
                        'SubCategory' => $row['sub_category'],
                        'Produk' => $row['produk'],
                        'Peruntukan' => $row['peruntukan'],
                        'Currency' =>  $row['currency'],
                        'Kurs' => $row['kurs'],

                    ]);
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: 503 is a web server error, so what does the web server logs report as the error?

Comment: if you solve your server problem you'll still have the problem that the maximum of rows for an excel-sheet is 1048576

Comment: This can be because of a number of reasons, including request timeout or memory overflow. Check your PHP and webserver logs for the error. Also, consider running tasks like this in a background job.

Comment: i have requested on my server. cause time uploading in php just 2 minutes.. if reach max times its just make show server logs report error 503.

Answer (score 0):

As I see you using a foreach loop, maybe it's a good thing to read up on how to use less memory looping over huge sets of data in Laravel.

This is a great article: https://blackdeerdev.com/laravel-chunk-vs-cursor/

In short: [the chunk function](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-chunk) could keep memory usage low. Also you can [increase the max exececution time](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) for PHP

Comment: it really need artisan or not?,when i try it says error

Comment: I really don't understand your comment. You don't need to run any artisan command. Just try to use arrays in a smarter way.